# Add Organisation & Contact to Insightly and automatically link them

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, insightly

I am using a PHP library (https://github.com/Insightly/insightly-php) with great success for the Insightly API. More information on the Insightly API can be found here: https://api.insight.ly/v2.2/Help

My goal is to have an organisation and a contact added to Insightly on a form submission and to then link the two together. I can add the organisation and the contact without any issues but I am having troubles linking the two afterwards. When I add in the code to link the two it is only adding the organisation and not the contact.

Please view my code below:

```
$organization = $i->addOrganization($newOrganization);
$getOrganizationID = $i->getOrganization($company);

$id = json_decode($getOrganizationID, true);

$newContact = (object)array(
"FIRST_NAME" => $first_name,
"LAST_NAME" => $last_name,
"CONTACTINFOS" => array(
(object)array(
"TYPE" => "EMAIL",
"LABEL" => "WORK",
"DETAIL" => $email,
),
(object)array(
"TYPE" => "PHONE",
"LABEL" => "WORK",
"DETAIL" => $phone,
)
),
"LINKS" => array(
(object)array(
"ORGANISATION_ID" => $id[0]['ORGANISATION_ID'],
)
),
);

$contact = $i->addContact($newContact);
```

Comment: The following line of code seems to be breaking my code:  
   ' $getOrganizationID = $i->getOrganization($company);'  
The function that is being called is as follows:  
     'public function getOrganization($id){
    return $this->GET("/v2.1/Organisations/$id")->asJSON();
  }'  
Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a faulty link in the getOrganization() function and have since fixed it.